# Difference in results of Portfolio optimization using scipy python and excel

Tags: python, excel, scipy, portfolio

I am running a simple portfolio optimization problem where my objective is to minimize the risk such that the risk has the following traditional formula

```
def cov(w):
     var = (np.array(w).T * covariance * np.array(w)).sum() # var= wT * covarianceMatrix * w
     return var
```

The covariance matrix for 4 assets in my case is

```
covariance = [[  2.63295509e-05, -1.07217702e-05 ,  3.21349026e-05,   4.30288472e-06],
 [ -1.07217702e-05  , 9.54978397e-05,  -9.09700572e-05 , -7.85486906e-06],
 [  3.21349026e-05 , -9.09700572e-05 ,  7.12920574e-03  , 6.64849327e-05],
 [  4.30288472e-06  ,-7.85486906e-06  , 6.64849327e-05 ,  8.64951187e-05]]
```

Using scipy I am running the following code:

```
res = minimize(lambda x: cov(x), [0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25],  method='SLSQP',bounds = ((0.0, 1.0),)*4
                ,options = {'disp':True, 'ftol': 1e-20, 'maxiter': 1000}
                , constraints={'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: sum(x) - 1)
print(res.x) # optimal_weights = [  5.55111512e-17,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]
print(res.fun) # optimal_function_val = -1.4048856813e-05
```

The results are illogical because logically risk cannot be negative. On the other hand, I am solving the same problem in Excel Solver with GRG Nonlinear method and it gives the following results.

```
optimal_weights = [0.61 0.23    0.00    0.16]
optimal_function_val = 1.43109E-05
```

The results in excel solver seems logical. Can someone guide me where I am doing wrong in Python ? Thanks.

Comment: In your definition of `cov()`, you use `*`, but with numpy arrays, `*` is *element-wise* multiplication.  For matrix multiplication, use the `dot()` method.  (Or, if you are using a sufficiently new version of Python 3 and numpy, you can use `@`.)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even know that @ works as matrix multiplacation operator. It works